# Animating slides on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a slider but I'm trying to animate the left and right boxes to fade in separately timed, left fading in faster than the right.

I've tried to make a jQuery script using the little knowledge I have but unfortunately it doesn't work, I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction with this/show me how it should be done.

```js
window.location.hash = 'slide-1';

$(".control").click(function () {
  $('.vs-box-left').fadeIn(100);
  $('.vs-box-right').fadeIn(200);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h3 {
   font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
   font-weight: 700;
   letter-spacing: 0.16em;
   line-height: 1.1;
   text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 26px;
}

/** VS Slider **/

.vs-slider {
  height: 470px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1110px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.vs-slide {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;

  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.vs-slide:target {
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.vs-controls {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.vs-controls li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.vs-controls li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

/** Slides **/

.vs-box-text h3, .vs-box-text p {
  color: #fff;
}

.vs-box-container {
  width: 1110px; /*Remove to let it fill cont*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.vs-box-left, .vs-box-right {
  max-width: 50%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 380px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #000;
  position: relative;
}

.vs-box-text {
  padding: 75px;
}

.vs-box-left .vs-box-text {
  margin-right: 80px;
}

.vs-box-right .vs-box-text {
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.vs-box-left {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #214860 0%, #61BEB7 100%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.vs-box-right {
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, #0870b7 0%, #0d3757 100%);
}

.vs-box-text span {
  border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

.vs-box-circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 80px;
 width: 160px;
 height: 160px; 
  background: #fff;
  left: 48%;
  top: 250px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  z-index: 20;
  text-align: center;
}

.vs-box-circle h3 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #0D2345;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 160px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vs-slider">
  <div class="vs-box-circle">
    <h3>VS</h3>
  </div>
 <!-- First Slide -->
<div class="vs-slide" id="slide-1">
  
  <div class="vs-box-left">
    <div class="vs-box-text">
      <h3><span>Slide 1</span></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="vs-box-right">
    <div class="vs-box-text">
      <h3><span>Slide 1</span></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /First Slide -->
<!-- Second Slide -->
<div class="vs-slide" id="slide-2">
  <div class="vs-box-left">
    <div class="vs-box-text">
      <h3><span>Slide 2</span></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="vs-box-right">
    <div class="vs-box-text">
      <h3><span>Slide 2</span></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <!-- /Second Slide -->
 <!-- Third SLide -->
<div class="vs-slide" id="slide-3">
  <div class="vs-box-left">
    <div class="vs-box-text">
      <h3><span>Slide 3</span></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="vs-box-right">
    <div class="vs-box-text">
      <h3><span>Slide 3</span></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Third Slide -->
</div>
<!-- VS Slider Controls -->
<ul class="vs-controls">
  <li class="control"><a href="#slide-1"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i></a></li>
  <li class="control"><a href="#slide-2"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i></a></li>
  <li class="control"><a href="#slide-3"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i></a></li>
</ul>
<!-- /VS Slider Controls -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `hide()` in your fade in like this.

```js
window.location.hash = 'slide-1';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".control").click(function () {
      $(".vs-box-left").hide().fadeIn(1000);
      $('.vs-box-right').hide().fadeIn(2000);
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h3 {
   font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
   font-weight: 700;
   letter-spacing: 0.16em;
   line-height: 1.1;
   text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 26px;
}

/** VS Slider **/

.vs-slider {
  height: 470px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1110px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.vs-slide {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;

  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.vs-slide:target {
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.vs-controls {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.vs-controls li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.vs-controls li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

/** Slides **/

.vs-box-text h3, .vs-box-text p {
  color: #fff;
}

.vs-box-container {
  width: 1110px; /*Remove to let it fill cont*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.vs-box-left, .vs-box-right {
  max-width: 50%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 380px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #000;
  position: relative;
}

.vs-box-text {
  padding: 75px;
}

.vs-box-left .vs-box-text {
  margin-right: 80px;
}

.vs-box-right .vs-box-text {
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.vs-box-left {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #214860 0%, #61BEB7 100%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.vs-box-right {
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, #0870b7 0%, #0d3757 100%);
}

.vs-box-text span {
  border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

.vs-box-circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 80px;
 width: 160px;
 height: 160px; 
  background: #fff;
  left: 48%;
  top: 250px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  z-index: 20;
  text-align: center;
}

.vs-box-circle h3 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #0D2345;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 160px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vs-slider">
  <div class="vs-box-circle">
    <h3>VS</h3>
  </div>
 <!-- First Slide -->
<div class="vs-slide" id="slide-1">
  
  <div class="vs-box-left">
    <div class="vs-box-text">
      <h3><span>Slide 1</span></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="vs-box-right">
    <div class="vs-box-text">
      <h3><span>Slide 1</span></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /First Slide -->
<!-- Second Slide -->
<div class="vs-slide" id="slide-2">
  <div class="vs-box-left">
    <div class="vs-box-text">
      <h3><span>Slide 2</span></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="vs-box-right">
    <div class="vs-box-text">
      <h3><span>Slide 2</span></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <!-- /Second Slide -->
 <!-- Third SLide -->
<div class="vs-slide" id="slide-3">
  <div class="vs-box-left">
    <div class="vs-box-text">
      <h3><span>Slide 3</span></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="vs-box-right">
    <div class="vs-box-text">
      <h3><span>Slide 3</span></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Third Slide -->
</div>
<!-- VS Slider Controls -->
<ul class="vs-controls">
  <li class="control"><a href="#slide-1"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i></a></li>
  <li class="control"><a href="#slide-2"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i></a></li>
  <li class="control"><a href="#slide-3"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i></a></li>
</ul>
<!-- /VS Slider Controls -->
```

Comment: Something so simple! Thank you!